# ag grid min height for autoHeight

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am wondering if there is a way that the ag-grid can have a min height when using `domLayout = true` ? When there are no rows it will show the spinner but it does not look good because the height of the grid is so short. I have tried some css `min-height` on the container and the style of the grid being `style="width: 100%; height: 100%` but that did not make a difference.

Anyone come across this and able to get a min height so the grid is not so short when there are a small amount of records?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you share a link or some code to be understandable? Screenshot also might be useful. Also can you tell us your Angular and Ag-grid versions please?

Answer (score 7):

I recently had a similar issue. I forced a min-height by using the following CSS:

```
.ag-center-cols-clipper,
.ag-center-cols-container {
  min-height: 300px !important;
}
```

Note that if you are using pinned columns, or other advanced features, you may need to override more styles.